# Prove that nim multiplication is associative and distributive

Tags: combinatorics, induction, combinatorial-game-theory

Let $\oplus$ represent nim-addition, and let $\otimes$ represent nim-multiplication. We define nim-addition as bitwise exclusive or. We define nim-multiplication recursively as follows:

$$
x\otimes y=\text{mex}\{(a\otimes x)\oplus (b\otimes y)\oplus (a\otimes b):0\leq a<x, 0\leq b<y\},
$$
where the $\text{mex}$ of a set $S$ is the minimum nonnegative integer that is not in $S$.

Prove that

- $(x\otimes y)\otimes z=x\otimes(y\otimes z)$ for all $x,y,z$; and
- $x\otimes(y\oplus z)=(x\otimes) y\oplus (x\otimes z)$ for all $x,y,z$.

In the book I'm reading it says that this is a routine induction. However, I'm not so confident in how to do this. Starting with associativity, my instict was to expand $(x\otimes y)\otimes z$ into
$$
\text{mex}\{(a\otimes(x\otimes y))\oplus(b\otimes z)\oplus(a\otimes b):a<x\otimes y, b<z\},
$$
and then try to rearrange this into a form that is similar to the expansion for $x\otimes(y\otimes z)$. But I cannot see a way of doing this. What am I missing for this 'routine' induction? Any help appreciated!

Comment: I think it is _not_ a simple induction proof, in that you need a lemma. It is proved in _On Numbers and Games_, Theorem 38. I am trying to write an answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not figure this out either, so I looked up the proof in *On Numbers and Games*, where Conway originally developed the theory of nimbers. In Conway's notation, $a'$ is always a variable which ranges over $\{0,1,\dots,a-1\}$, so that the addition and multiplication definitions can be written more succinctly as
$$
a+b:=\text{mex}\{a+b',\;\;a'+b\}\\
\hspace{1cm}ab:=\text{mex}\{a'b+ab'+a'b'\}
$$

Conway uses the following fact as a lemma in his proofs:

> **Lemma:** Let $a,b\in \mathbb N$. Let $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ such that $\{0,1,\dots,a-1\}\subseteq A$, and $a\notin A$. Similarly, let  $B\subseteq \mathbb N$ such that $\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}\subseteq B$, and $b\notin B$. Then
> $$
> a+b=\text{mex}\{a^*+b,a+b^*\mid a^*\in A,b^*\in B\}\\
> ab=\newcommand{\mex}{\operatorname{mex}}\mex \{ab^*+a^*b+a^*b^*\mid a^*\in A,b^*\in B\}
> $$
>
> *Proof sketch:* We are taking the definitons of $a+b$ and $ab$, and adding in some extra exlcudants. As long as we can show  $$ a^*+b\neq a+b,\qquad a+b^*\neq a+b,\qquad a^*b+b^*a+a^*b^*\neq ab,$$whenever $a^*>a$ or $b^*>b,$ then none of the added numbers will change the mex. The first two should be obvious. Proving the last is equivalent to showing
> $$
> a^*b^*\neq a^*b+ab^*+ab,
> $$
> This is true provided $a^*>a$ and $b^*>b$, since $a^*b+ab^*+ab$ is one of the excludants in the definition of $a^*b^*$. The other cases where $a^*>a$ and $b^*<b$, and where $a^*<a$ and $b^*>b$, are similar.

---

With this lemma, we can now give a simple proof by induction. Let's start with distributivity, since we need that to prove associativity. From the lemma, we can write
$$
(a+b)c=\text{mex}\{s^*c+(a+b)c'+s^*c'\mid s^*\in S,\color{gray}{c'<c}\},
$$
where $S$ is any subset which contains all the numbers less than $a+b$, and does not contain $a+b$. In particular, we will take
$
S=\{a+b',a'+b\}.
$
This means
$$
(a+b)c=\mex\{(a'+b)c+(a+b)c'+(a'+b)c',\;\;(a+b')c+(a+b)c'+(a+b')c'\}
$$

By induction, we can assume the distributive property for all of the simpler excludants, so
$$
(a+b)c=\mex\{(a'c+ac'+a'c')+bc,\;\; ac+(b'c+bc'+b'c')\}\tag1
$$
On the other hand,
$$
ac+bc=\mex\{p^*+bc,ac+q^*\mid p^*\in P,q^*\in Q\}
$$
where $P$ contains all numbers less than $ac$, but excludes $ac$, and $Q$ contains all numbers less than $bc$, but excludes $bc$. In particular, we can take $P=\{a'c+ac'+a'c'\}$ and $Q=\{b'c+bc'+b'c'\}$, in which case we recover $(1)$ exactly, completing the proof.

---

Now, onto associativity. We can write
$$
(ab)c=\text{mex}\{p^*c+(ab)c'+p^*c\}
$$
where $p^*$ ranges over any set containing all numbers less than $ab$, but not $ab$. In particular, we let $p^*$ range over $\{a'b+ab'+a'b'\}$, which gives
\begin{align}
(ab)c
&=\text{mex}\{(a'b+ab'+a'b')c+(ab)c'+(a'b+ab'+a'b')c'\}
\\&=\text{mex}\{a'bc+ab'c+a'b'c+abc'+a'bc'+ab'c'+a'b'c'\}\tag2
\end{align}
In the second equality, we use the distributive property, *and* we use the fact that we can inductively assume associativity for the simpler products to omit parentheses. The proof is completed by expanding $a(bc)$ using the same strategy, and noting the expression is equal to $(2)$.

Comment: Wow this is extremely helpful! Sincere thanks Mike Earnest :)